# Configure read-only attribute for jmx mbean with xml spring configuration

Tags: spring, jmx, mbeans, spring-jmx

How to configure read-only JMX bean with XML configuration?

Official tutorial (link below) says only about annotations on methods, is there a way to do the same via XML?

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jmx.html#jmx-interface-metadata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [AbstractConfigurableMBeanInfoAssembler](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jmx/export/assembler/AbstractConfigurableMBeanInfoAssembler.html) and its subclasses [MethodNameBasedMBeanInfoAssembler](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jmx/export/assembler/MethodNameBasedMBeanInfoAssembler.html) etc.

See also [the MBeanInfoAssembler Interface](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jmx.html#jmx-interface-assembler) section in the reference documentation.